# Node.js + ajax, uploading a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I've been trying to upload a file with node.js and ajax, yet i can't let it work. I don't get an error, but nothing is in my storage folder.

index.js:

```
app.post('/newFlavour', function(req, res){
console.log("[INFO] New flavour request: " + req.body.name);

let form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.uploadDir = path.join(__dirname, '/storage');

form.on('file', function(field, file) {
    fs.rename(file.path, path.join(form.uploadDir, file.name));
});

form.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('An error has occured: \n' + err);
});

form.on('end', function() {
    console.log('success');
});

form.parse(req); });
```

My function with the ajax request:

```
function createFlavour() {
let file = $('#upload-input').get(0).files;
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('uploads', file, file.name);

console.log(file)

$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/newFlavour",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        name: $('#name').val(),
        file: file
    }),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error occured");
    },
    complete: function () {
        console.log("complete")
    }
});

clearModal();  }
```

The input tag:

```
<input id="upload-input" type="file" name="upload"></br>
```

I don't know what i am missing here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `I don't get an error`, or maybe you do.. Your silently ignoring any errors in 2 places I can see,.. one on your `fs.rename`, and again on the `form.parse`,.. get the error handling sorted and it might give you a clue to the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should parse your `req` at the start. Also per [formidable documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable)

> **fileBegin**
>
> Emitted whenever a new file is detected in the upload stream. Use this
>   event if you want to stream the file to somewhere else while buffering
>   the upload on the file system.
>
> form.on('fileBegin', function(name, file) { });

so doing this should save your file

```
app.post('/newFlavour', function (req, res){
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(req);

    form.on('fileBegin', function (name, file){
        file.path = __dirname + '/storage/' + file.name;
    });

    form.on('file', function (name, file){
        console.log('Uploaded ' + file.name);
    });

    res.status(200);
});
```

Also you ajax Post is wrong, this should work

```
    var data = new FormData();
    $.each($('#upload-input')[0].files, function(i, file) {
        data.append('file-'+i, file);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/newFlavour',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        method: 'POST',
        type: 'POST', // For jQuery < 1.9
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I moved that line to the top. Yet nothing happends. If i console log my formdata on line 6 at functions.js, this is the output: FormData {}. I think something is going wrong there

Comment: @Stanos, I have implemented the above code, but I still get a failed response in the network tab of the devtools for the request

Comment: what should I do for that?

Comment: how to pass some JSON data along with the file in ajax?

Comment: Its a Form so you either pass each param into the form or stringify your JSON add it in then Form and then parse at backend.